# Node group and using multiple geometries / objects

Tags: geometry-nodes, groups

I'm trying to create an object cutter node group then add it to my asset manager.

Example: you have two objects and one object is used to cut out a hole from another
one.

I can get the nodes to work with the **bolt object** but when I change the cutter object to try and use the **Cutter Cube it fails** due to different socket types.  Which socket types should I be using?

[image: img0]

[image: img0a]

Node Group
[image: img1]

I tried connecting two geometry sockets to the input but I get an error.

[image: img3]

See attached file:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use "geometry" as type like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: i was too lazy to rename "hole tolerant" to "cutter geometry" - sorry for that.